# How do I enable VS Code to autocomplete the path to my image directory in the local host?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete

How do you enable autocomplete the VS code to search for the path of the file and directory in the VS code ?

I used to be able to autocomplete path or file to my directory but recently the VS code is not working?

Comment: what language mode is the editor in in which you are trying to get this behaviour?

Comment: If you want help with a specific problem (unlike the general answer I've given below), then please also add steps to reproduce your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general answer (not really about any specific problem):

There are a few settings in vanilla VS Code which allow controlling this, shown below along with their default values:

```json
"markdown.suggest.paths.enabled": true,
"markdown.suggest.paths.includeWorkspaceHeaderCompletions": "onDoubleHash",
"javascript.suggest.paths": true,
"typescript.suggest.paths": true
```

Each of those features apply in specific scenarios. For example, the JS/TS ones contributed by the builtin TypeScript Language Features extension purposely only apply in the context of module imports/exports.

Check if you accidentally changed the value of any of those settings. In many other language modes with vanilla VS Code, suggestions for paths should also just work (due to being contributed by a corresponding language support extension). Ex.

- `@import url("./...")` in CSS
- `src="..."` and `href="..."` in HTML

If something is wrong with those, I'd suggest searching for bug reports using google search queries like "`github vscode issues path suggestions not working`", or "`site:github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues path suggestions not working`" (along with keywords related to the language mode and context it's not working for, of course). If the language mode's language support is provided by a specific extension, then google instead with keywords for that extension, or use the `site:` modifier to search under the issues path for that extension.

There will be be some scenarios where such suggestions are not possible based on static analysis, such as if these paths do not exist in the development directory structure, and only exist at runtime, being provided by something like a webserver.

There are extensions in the extension marketplace that will add path suggestions in other contexts.